# Does disabling SSR in SvelteKit mean that all *.server.* files never run?

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I'm trying to understand what happens when SSR is disabled in SvelteKit. My understanding is that aside from the server not doing any of the rendering and hydration (i.e. not calling `load` from `+page.ts` files), that all `*.server.*` files will also never execute. Is that correct?

Does this also mean that things like [handleFetch](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handlefetch) wouldn't work anymore if SSR is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling SSR just means that the server does not generate fully formed HTML, instead it will just send code & data (also from server load functions).

Comment: Ah so `*.server.*` files and server `load` functions always execute, even with SSR off?

Comment: Yes, it will execute.